# Java new Date with time stamp in date format

Tags: java

I have used the following

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");  
Date date = new Date(); 
String formattedDate= df.format(date);

Date dateWithTime = df.parse(formattedDate);
```

i got the formatted date as string when i conver this into date i got error like

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Feb 26 11:45:43 IST 2013"
```

How would convert to date or how i format a current date and get as date?

Comment: I think something more along the lines of `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` might be closer.  If the hour is 24 clock, then you'll need `HH` instead...

Comment: your current code wouldn't throw parse exception, it could if you try to parse it into an invalid format but that's just a guess.. show us the right code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code wouldn't throw ParseException. But it sure would definitely yield wrong output. your format should be:

```
"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz"
```

**Note that**

- MM---> Months
- mm---> Minutes

**Test with your code with out correcting the format:**

```
Sat Jan 26 06:24:07 GMT 2013
```

**Test with your code with correcting the format:**

```
Tue Feb 26 06:20:51 GMT 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

The date format should be as follows as shown in the exception. Change it to -

```
EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss z yyyy
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct simpledateformat will be

`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the link for proper date formatting and parsing
[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)